# why mouse coodrinates not showing up

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

i am learning javascript DOM . wrote this code , there was lots of errors in console . finally everything is sorted out. but the mouse coordinates are not showing . learning about addEventListener and using querySelector. where am i doing wrong. stuck on it since two days.
Here is the JSFiddle :   https://jsfiddle.net/088a9at5/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>MouseEvent</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>

  <h1 onmouseover="style.color='red'" onmouseout="style.color='black'">Mouse over this text</h1>
  <div class="coordinateBox"></div>
  <div class="result"></div>


  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
.coordinateBox {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```
const RECT = document.querySelector(".coordinateBox");
const ANS = document.querySelector("result");

function mouseCoordinate(e) {
  var x = e.clientX;
  var y = e.clientY;
  var coo = "X : " + x + " Y : " + y;
  document.querySelector("result").innerHTML = coo
}
if(ANS){
  ANS.onclick = mouseCoordinate;
}
```

Comment: I assume that css and js in the code block here are in separate files?

Comment: first of all, you're missing the `.` in `document.querySelector("result")` which should be `document.querySelector(".result")`

Comment: @Cerbrus yes all are separate files.

Comment: additionnally, because `<div class="result">` is empty (no text inside), you can't click on it. the click handler is on it, maybe you wanted to target another element for the click?

Comment: @Kaddath i wanted it something like this https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_events_onmousemove

Comment: I have posted an answer assuming some things but i want you to clarify that where you want to show the coordinates and from which area they are selected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from corrrecting the selector name in querySelector to `querySelector('.result')`,
if you target the click on the element `ANS` it will never get fired because the element is of height and width 0;

Instead if you target  `RECT` it works,

https://jsfiddle.net/088a9at5/4/

Comment: Thanks a ton ! that was such a big mess. thank you soo much. i just messed it. as i had to show result in const ANS i thought i need to target that ! but what should have been done is i need to target the place on which the mouse moves , right ?

Comment: yes, the element that you want to receive the click event

Comment: and why do we need that if(ANS) thing , if we do not use that it shows null error.

Comment: that's  a more general js concept, if you try to create a property (in your case that's `onclick`) on null (what document.query selector returns if doesn't find the selector), you get an error.
   That `if` prevents that error.

Answer (score 3):

You were missing two . in `.result` and you need to create a listener on the rectangle, not on the result.

```js
const RECT = document.querySelector(".coordinateBox");
const ANS = document.querySelector(".result");

function mouseCoordinate(e) {
  var x = e.clientX;
  var y = e.clientY;
  var coo = "X : " + x + " Y : " + y;
  document.querySelector(".result").innerHTML = coo
}
if(ANS){
  RECT.onclick = mouseCoordinate;
}
```

```css
.coordinateBox {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<h1 onmouseover="style.color='red'" onmouseout="style.color='black'">Mouse over this text</h1>
<div class="coordinateBox"></div>
<div class="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the `.` in `document.querySelector("result")` which should be `document.querySelector(".result")`.

**The other major issue is that you haven't added an event listener.**

`RECT.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseCoordinate)`

Here is your ***[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/088a9at5/10/),*** which is now working.

Also, here is a very, simple ***[codepen](https://codepen.io/tOkyO1/pen/XqPwJw?editors=1111)*** which illustrates the nuts and bolts.

P.S. In your jsfiddle, you haven't styled `ANS`, so it's hard to tell what you want the click event to be attached to? And for some reason it's not letting me style the `.result` element :/

Comment: @Tarique give me a second and i'll figure it out

Comment: @Tarique see my comment, you may not be able to click on `result` because it's empty, add text in it and it will work

Comment: @Tarique i've included a codepen in my answer, with a very simple, working solution!

Comment: The major issue was not (!) the 'missing' event listener. Since he only wanted to display the result after a click his code was totally fine. Do not confuse people by saying that  `.onclick` does not work

Comment: @jdickel um... i didn't say `onclick` didn't work? what are you talking about?

Comment: You said, that 
>'The other major issue is that you haven't added an event listener
That is not correct.'< The major issue was, that the `.onclick`/ event listener was on the wrong class.

BTW: The fiddle is still not working for me

Comment: the codepen one is working ! thanks @Anthony.  jdickel yes , i had used the wrong const. have just started using event listeners.

Comment: @jdickel fiddles working fine for me. it is correct in the sense that if the event listener is attached to an unclickable item, then youve gotta add an event listener

Answer (score 0):

Based on your fiddle
Because you just missed the class identifier `.` in this line
 `const ANS = document.querySelector("result");` before `result`
It should be like this
`const ANS = document.querySelector(".result");`

Same thing with `document.querySelector("result").innerHTML = coo` this line.

And provide some height and width to your `result` div and border too so you can see in which area you have to click.